# Pandas: Add flag using a groupby calculation

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I want to first obtain the third quantiled grouped by (group and level in this example).

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'customer': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'], 
                  'group': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
                  'level': ['Z', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'X', 'X', 'Z'],
                  'value': [0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.7, 0.5, 0.2]})

d.groupby(['group', 'level']).quantile(0.75)
```

Now that I have the quantile for each group. I want to add a column on the original df based on the groupby value.

```
   0.75 value
group   level   
A   X   0.67
    Z   0.45
B   X   0.65
    Z   0.27
```

The result would be something like this where I'd add a new column based if the value is higher than the quantiled then I'll add 1, if it's lower then add a 0.

```
    customer    group   level   value     new
       1          A       Z       0.40     1
       2          B       X       0.60     0
```

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the first row be `0` in `new`, since `0.4` is lower than `0.45`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
d['new'] = (d.value > d.groupby(['group', 'level'])['value']
                       .transform('quantile', 0.75)).astype(int)

>>> d
  customer group level  value  new
0        1     A     Z    0.4    0
1        2     B     X    0.6    0
2        3     B     X    0.7    1
3        4     A     X    0.6    0
4        5     B     Z    0.3    1
5        6     A     Z    0.5    1
6        7     B     Z    0.2    0
7        8     A     X    0.7    1
8        9     B     X    0.5    0
9       10     A     Z    0.2    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only `lt` and index matching

```
q = d.groupby(['group', 'level']).quantile(0.75)
d.set_index(['group', 'level']).value.lt(q.value).astype(int)

group  level
A      X        1
       X        0
       Z        1
       Z        0
       Z        1
B      X        1
       X        0
       X        1
       Z        0
       Z        1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```